# Does C copy the element every time you access an array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

C can't return references unlike C++. Does that mean if you access `A[i]` it will copy the element in evaluating the expression?

For example if `A` is an array of 10 `int`s, does `A[5]+=1;` only increment the temporary copy built when evaluating `A[5]`, unlike C++'s vector which will increment the actual sixth element itself?

Comment: `A[5]` dereferences the array element directly, no temporary copies involved.

Comment: `A[5] += 1` increments the fitth zero-based element of the array `A`. If it doesn't do that, the compiler has a bug. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: `A[5]+=1` is just the same as  `A[5] =  A[5] + 1` , an optimizing compiler would make as few copies, if any at all, as can possibly be expressed by the machine  language.

Comment: Make sure you understand how `a = 3;` does not read `a` ... it is no different for array member access

Answer (score 12):

C has a concept called an 'lvalue' which is sort-of like a reference.  It's not a type (not part of the type system), but certain C expressions are 'lvalues', and only such expressions can be the left operand of an assignment (including an op-assign) or an increment/decrement.

Since C has no operator overloading, there's no need to have a distinction in the type system as there's never any need to declare things as rvalues vs lvalues.  It was the desire to add operator overloading in C++ that lead to the introduction of reference types to make the rvalue/lvalue distinction clear for overloaded operators.

Answer (score 5):

If that was true, you would be unable to modify arrays at all and the expression `A[5]+=1;` would have no effect!

On the opposite, when you pass a scalar argument to a function, it behaves like a copy because it is not modified upon return. But an array, in fact passed as a pointer, is not copied (that would be unbearably costly) and can be different upon return.

Answer (score 4):

> does A[5]+=1; only increment the temporary copy built when evaluating A[5]

No. `A[5]+=1;` will cause the 6th element of `A` to be incremented by 1.

That is likely to be achieved by copying `A[5]` into a register in the CPU, incrementing it and copying the value back.

Here's a program:

```
int main(){
    int A[10];
    A[5]+=1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the gcc generated x86-64 assembler for `A[5]+=1;`

```
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
    add     eax, 1
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], eax
```

That moves `DWORD PTR [rbp-28]` into the 32-bit EAX accumulator, adds 1 to it and moves it back to the same place.

`DWORD PTR [rbp-28]` identifies the 6th element of `A` by its position relative to (end of) the stack-frame (`rbp`).

The point about references is a red-herring. Both C and C++ are compiling to machine code (possibly via assembler). What other features the languages have has no affect on how `A[5]+=1;` is interpreted or compiled.

Answer (score 3):

C always copies an element when *reading* from an array with `A[i]`, that is, when the expression `A[i]` is an “rvalue”. However, when considering *writes*, C has a notion of “lvalue” expressions, which are essentially a restricted subset of expression syntax that are allowed to appear as the destination of an assignment:

```
X    = Y
*X   = Y
X[i] = Y
X.n  = Y
```

In these cases, the “expressions” `*X`, `X[i]`, and `X.n` don’t actually evaluate to values—they have the same *syntax* as expressions, for convenience, but not the same *semantics*. You can think of these as something more like the following:

```
memcpy(&X,    &Y, sizeof(Y));
memcpy(&*X,   &Y, sizeof(Y));
memcpy(&X[i], &Y, sizeof(Y));
memcpy(&X.n,  &Y, sizeof(Y));
```

Or, alternatively, think of C as having *multiple* different assignment operators:

```
_    = _  // direct assignment
*_   = _  // indirect assignment
_[_] = _  // special case of indirect assignment
_._  = _  // special case of indirect assignment
```

Either way, an assignment such as `A[5] += 1` will increment the value of the sixth element of `A` in place, just as you would expect, which you can verify like so:

```
int A[1] = { 1 };
A[0] += 5;
printf("%d\n", A[0]);  // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

no, i array index is just a pointer so only a location is passed instead of whole array and the value of actual memory location is affected.

try the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function(int[]);
int main()
{
    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d, ",a[i]);    
    function(a);
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d, ",a[i]);
    return 0;
}

void function(int b[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        b[i] *= 10;
}
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFH63.jpg)